# renaming attributes on a shapefile in r

Tags: r, shapefile, rgdal

I am trying to join a subset of two similar shapefiles, one with states from the US and the second with provinces from Canada. The datasets are available here: [shapefiles from Geocommons](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/27cft3118dha6xt/AACH6Y9o5fH_MwarH9_GSuN1a)

I noticed that in the two files the attributes are slightly different. In the US map, states are labeled as "STATE_NAME" but in the Canadian map the attributes are simply "NAME". This is a problem because I cannot join the two shapefiles into a single one. Does anyone have a work around for this?

here is my code so far:

```
require (raster)

#load in boundaries for plotting 
state <- readOGR(dsn = '/usa_state_shapefile.shp', layer = "usa_state_shapefile")
projection(state) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs")
# Subset US shapefile by desired states
nestates <- c("Maine", "Vermont", "Massachusetts", "New Hampshire" ,"Connecticut",
              "Rhode Island","New York","Pennsylvania", "New Jersey",
              "Maryland", "Delaware", "Virginia", "West Virginia", "North Carolina")
state.sub <- state[as.character(state@data$STATE_NAME) %in% nestates, ]
summary(state.sub)

provinces<-readOGR (dsn = '/canadian_provinces.shp', layer = "canadian_provinces")
projection(provinces) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs")
canprov<- c ("Quebec", "Ontario", "Newfoundland  & Labrador", "New Brunswick", "Prince Edward Island", "Nova Scotia")
provinces.sub <- provinces[as.character(provinces@data$NAME) %in% canprov,]
summary (provinces.sub)
```

Im guessing that if I rename the attributes to the same thing like "NAME" then I should be able to merge the two shapefiles using some sort of `rbind` or `cbind` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think this is all that is needed:

```
names(state.sub@data)[names(state.sub@data)=="STATE_NAME"] <- "NAME"
```

You should then be able to join the data sets with

```
provinces_and_states <- rbind(state.sub, provinces.sub)
```

Alternatively, you could probably get the data from [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/).

Comment: Natural Earth seems to work way better than my original plan, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This also works if you have only one name:

```
names(shpdata@data) <- "newname"
```